# Accessing Views inside fragment

Tags: android, fragment, nullreferenceexception, android-fragmentactivity

I'm having troubles accessing the Views that within my Fragment. In the example below, I can't access the 2nd button that is within the Fragment (e.g., *findViewById* appears to return NULL and the app crashes when I try b2.setText("test") ), but when I directly add it in the activity_main.xml, it does work.

Here is the code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Button fragmentButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.iMainButton);

    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.iMainInnerLLContainer, new TestFragment());         
    ft.commit();

    final Button b2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.iTestFragmentInnerButton);
    if(b2 == null) { Log.d("MainActivity.java:", "b2 is null"); } 
    else { Log.d("MainActivity.java:", "b2 is NOT null"); } 

    fragmentButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            // do stuff here
        }
    });
}

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/iMainRootLinearLayoutContainer"
android:orientation="vertical" 
>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/iMainButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Add fragment..." 
/>    

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/iMainInnerLLContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
>
    <!-- Fragment goes here, can reference button if it is added here manually -->
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**TestFragment.java**

```
public class TestFragment extends Fragment 
{
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.ltestfragment, container, false);
}
}
```

**ltestfragment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:id="@+id/iTestFragmentOuterLinearLayout"
>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/iTestFragmentInnerButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="This is my test fragment button." 
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I think I'm missing something very basic here and I would appreciate some insight on what that might be.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hmm, this is getting weirder: I got it to work by adding the fragment to an actual <fragment> tag. However, shouldn't it work just the same when adding a fragment to a ViewGroup?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set up a textchangelistener in your fragment.

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {

TextChangeListener listener;

public interface TextChangeListener {
    public void onTextChange(CharSequence newText);
}
```

```
public void setTextChangeListener(TextChangeListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}
```

Then, in your activity, set up the listener :

```
public class ActivityAB extends FragmentActivity {

FragmentA fragmentA;
FragmentB fragmentB;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ab);

    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentA = (FragmentA) manager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentA);
    fragmentB = (FragmentB) manager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentB);

    fragmentA.setTextChangeListener(new TextChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChange(CharSequence newText) {
            fragmentB.updateTextValue(newText);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know how to implement what you are suggesting in my example. There is no text in it and you use _findFragmentById_, which I don't think I can even use because I'm not using a <fragment> container (so which id would I use?). Plus, I thought I should generally be able to access the elements of my activity.

Comment: I've tried some more to get your code to work for my example above, but I fail at this line: [ fragmentA = (FragmentA) manager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentA); ] ... which was my problem from the beginning - I can't find my Views/Fragments and therefore don't even get to set up the ChangeListener.

Answer (score 0):

Implement an interface to listen to the events of a fragment from its activity.

Code in Fragment:-

```
   public class TestFragment extends Fragment  
   {
       public interface OnClickListener 
       {
            public void onButtonClicked(<data type><data>);  
       }

       b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       @Override    
            public void onClick(View v) {
            listener.onButtonClicked(<<pass some values here>>);
            }
       });
   }
```

Code in Main:-

```
   MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements TestFragment.OnClickListener, 
   {
        @Override
        public void onButtonClicked(<<receive the pased data here>>) {

        //do some stuff here with the received data after the button is clicked
    } 
   }
```

Comment: I tried to get this to work, but this line is the crux of the matter that I can't solve: [ _b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()_ ]. Where and how to get b2, especially in the fragment?

Comment: //in the createView method add this line                                                                b2 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.iTestFragmentInnerButton);